# Dynamic Screens in mobile APP using Sitecore CMS

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk, mobile

Is it possible to control `mobile screens/layout` using Sitecore CMS?

I have a requirement to modify the mobile screen based on data from `Sitecore JSS`. 
 Using a `configuration` is also acceptable.

Is it possible to send the data using `Sitecore JSS` so that the client can utilize the CMS capabilities in their `mobile app (iOS/Android)`?

Any guidance on which direction we should pursue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can set device specific presentation in Sitecore CMS. This is an old provision that Sitecore provided but due to responsive implementation, I have not used it much. You can utilize it now, though I have not tried it with Layout Service.

Comment: @VikrantPunwatkar: Yes we can send the device specific data using device settings for mobile apps. Wanted to explore the option of dynamic rendering in mobile app using the data from CMS.